# CSS Blur elements selectively

Tags: css, filter

I'm trying to get a smart looking modal popup by using a blur filter e.g. `-webkit-filter: blur(10px);`. This works great when I apply the blur to a specific element like this:

```
body.modal_open #main { -webkit-filter: blur(10px); }
```

However, if my modal popup is within #main, the filter is applied to that element too, as you'd expect.

My question is, would there be a way to tell the browser not to apply the filter to a specific element? I tried to add:

```
body.modal_open .modal_window { -webkit-filter: blur(0px); }
```

But that didn't work. Is there a way to do this based on the z-index of an element, or something similar? I can't find any CSS to select elements based on z-index, so I'm guessing that's not possible.

Is the only option to bring all the modal windows out of the `#main` container? Or are there any more ideas out there?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `body.modal_open .modal_window { -webkit-filter: blur(0px) !important; }` will probably override it. You used an `#id` before, that's more specific.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that - unfortunately that doesn't seem to do the trick though. I understand there is a backdrop-filter that might be more appropriate [(details)](https://webkit.org/demos/backdrop-filter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody looking for an answer to this, I never found a way to use z-index or anything similar to apply the `filter: blur` to specific layers. However, by using backdrop filter:

```
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px); backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
```

I managed to achieve the desired effect. Note that this method is [only supported in Safari and Chrome](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter) at the moment, but hopefully more browsers will support this in the coming months and years, because it looks pretty great!